# How to use public method in another class

Tags: java

I have a class named PointOfSale which have a public method getTpid, but I failed when I want to call this method in my main class, I can only call "TPID_FIELD_NUMBER", how to solve this problem?

```
PointOfSale ps = new PointOfSale();
ps.TPID_FIELD_NUMBER; //correct
ps.getTpid();// error
```

```
public final class PointOfSale implements PointOfSaleOrBuilder {
   public static final int TPID_FIELD_NUMBER = 1;
   private int tpid_;

  @java.lang.Override
  public int getTpid() {
    return tpid_;
  }
}
```

```
public interface PointOfSaleOrBuilder {
  
  int getTpid();

}
```

Comment: You need to call `ps.getTpid()`, not `ps.getTpid`. Also, should that value have a default value? You also are not getting the integer, just calling the method.

Comment: You aren't using the correct syntax. The correct syntax how you call a method should be covered in most tutorials: [The Java™ Tutorials - using objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html)

Comment: Also remember the semicolons.  This just looks like a typo to me.

Comment: after I add (), I got error Unresolved reference: getTpid

Comment: `@java.lang.Override` 1) what is being overridden? 2) `java.lang` is implicit, you don't need to write it, unless you have another `Override` annotation shadowing it. My gut feeling is that the second class is not compiling because of that `Override` annotation and you're actually referring to an older version that didn't have that method.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I edited the code, it implements an interface

Comment: Ok, this is the second edit that drastically changes the meaning of your code. Can you please post something that actually reproduces the issue and stick to it?

Comment: @Alex Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have. Also include the full complete error message you get from the compiler.

Comment: Anyway, I tried your code and it compiles fine (removing `ps.TPID_FIELD_NUMBER;` because, despite what you state in your question, that line on itself is not a statement and therefore gives a syntax error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you just need to add () at the end of your call.

ps.TPID_FIELD_NUMBER is a call for a constant.
If you want to call a method, you should call like this: ps.getTpid();

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     PointOfSale ps = new PointOfSale();
     ps.getTpid();
}
```

Comment: Hi, after I add (), I got error Unresolved reference: getTpid

Comment: Ok, I see you changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the line "ps.TPID_FIELD_NUMBER;". This will give "Not a statement" error. You should assign it to a variable for successful execution.

Your code should look like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PointOfSale ps = new PointOfSale();
    int num = ps.TPID_FIELD_NUMBER; 
    ps.getTpid();
}
```